# How to revert back the last merge in GIT

Tags: git, github, git-gui

I committed my changes to local master, I merged my changes with the works of another developer who was also working on master, she made few commit before my commit.  Finally I made a merge of my work to hers, now it happens that my commit overwrote her changes in the repository.  It is there anyway I can revert back the merge?

```
o - bad merge here that I want to get rid off
|\
| o her commit 1 yesterday
| o her commit 2 yesterday
| o her commit 3 yesterday
o | my commit today
\ |
 o
```

Comment: Check out http://git-scm.com/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just move back your master branch one step with `git reset <SHA>` (see [manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)), where <SHA> identifies the commit before the current one (the one you labelled "my commit today").
After that, you can look into the [git merge manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) for more info on how to prevent the overwriting of changes.